# Docker pull hangs on "extracting"

Tags: docker

Every pull I run hangs on "Extracting"

```
# docker -v pull ansible/awx_rabbitmq:3.7.4
3.7.4: Pulling from ansible/awx_rabbitmq
ff3a5c916c92: Extracting [>                                                  ]  32.77kB/2.066MB
5387f4b4c52b: Download complete 
dba8c403a5b6: Download complete 
4258fc50c523: Download complete 
41e241289d30: Download complete 
7a8ab8823f42: Download complete 
21ac0c0b3f13: Download complete 
56b9421a89dc: Download complete 
e69676b835e9: Download complete 
13a893bc00f9: Download complete 
e7cf78370af8: Download complete 
363d82081450: Download complete 
bc716b889e7b: Download complete 
ebd8aacef79e: Download complete 
839d6f7a7803: Download complete
```

this is the syslog output (docker daemon verbosity in debug):

```
Jan 26 13:10:56 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:56.216589013+01:00" level=debug msg="Calling HEAD /_ping"
Jan 26 13:10:56 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:56.216881715+01:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.41/info"
Jan 26 13:10:56 XXXMACHINENAME dbus-daemon[24071]: [session uid=0 pid=24069] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=24060 comm="docker-credential-secretservice get " label="unconfined")
Jan 26 13:10:56 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:56.274306708+01:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.41/images/create?fromImage=ansible%2Fawx_rabbitmq&tag=3.7.4"
Jan 26 13:10:56 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:56.275348977+01:00" level=debug msg="Trying to pull ansible/awx_rabbitmq from https://registry-1.docker.io v2"
Jan 26 13:10:57 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:57.668102153+01:00" level=debug msg="Pulling ref from V2 registry: ansible/awx_rabbitmq:3.7.4"
Jan 26 13:10:57 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:57.668519475+01:00" level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:dba8c403a5b6fbb5651fd71cc7e2c96605165864b4ee509d2b6676e2958b8164\""
Jan 26 13:10:57 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:57.668554305+01:00" level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:ff3a5c916c92643ff77519ffa742d3ec61b7f591b6b7504599d95a4a41134e28\""
...
Jan 26 13:10:58 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:10:58.548777211+01:00" level=debug msg="Using /usr/bin/unpigz to decompress"
...
Jan 26 13:11:04 XXXMACHINENAME dockerd[23893]: time="2022-01-26T13:11:04.347774528+01:00" level=debug msg="Downloaded ebd8aacef79e to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob810059367"
```

Not a disk space problem, the filesystem is almost empty.

Comment: I have the same issue, but `rm -rf /var/run/docker*` never fixed it.